# How to sort a list of lists according to list item which is a number represented as string in python?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have 3 lists:

```
>>> a = ["12", "a"]
>>> b = ["123", "b"]
>>> c = ["4", "c"]
```

I put them in a new list:

```
>>> d = [a,b,c]
```

When I sort them according to first item of each inner lists:

```
>>> sorted(d, key=itemgetter(0))
[['12', 'a'], ['123', 'b'], ['4', 'c']]
```

But I want:

```
[['4', 'c'], ['12', 'a'], ['123', 'b']]
```

Also, first item may have leading zero:

```
>>> a = ["012", "a"]
>>> b = ["0123", "b"]
>>> c = ["04", "c"]
```

Again, I want to see the sorted list this way:

```
[['04', 'c'], ['012', 'a'], ['0123', 'b']]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `int()` in the key getter:

```
In [5]: sorted(d, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
Out[5]: [['4', 'c'], ['12', 'a'], ['123', 'b']]
```

In the second example:

```
In [10]: sorted(d, key=lambda x:int(x[0]))
Out[10]: [['04', 'c'], ['012', 'a'], ['0123', 'b']]
```